# How can I print a text in c/c++/java without double quotes and apostrophes in source code

Tags: java, c++, c, double-quotes, apostrophe

How can I print a text for instance **programming language** without double quotes and apostrophes in source code? I made in c++ :

```
#include <iostream>
#define Rep(x) #x
int main()
{
   printf(Rep(programming language));
   return 0;
}
```

Program is ok but I wonder if there is another way to do this? and how do it in java? is any possibility do it in java?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Uhwell, you can't. String literals are defined in all of these three languages as being enclosed in double quotes. Even in your example, what you use is the preprocessor; the "real" source code will show `printf("programming language")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert code units as integer literals:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char[] string = { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x0A, 0x00 };
    std::cout << string;
}
```

In Java this should do:

```
byte[] bytes = {(byte)0x41, (byte)0x42, (byte)0x43, (byte)0x0A};
String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Uhm, this is really an array of bytes, not Unicode code points. Isn't there `wchar_t`? And it is superseded last I heard, right?

Comment: @fge I never said anything about code points. There is `char32_t` which can be used to represent code points.

Comment: Well then how do you print Unicode code point U+1F601 (a [smiley](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Unicode/Emoticons)) in C/C++, provided your display supports that?

Comment: @fge `std::cout << u8"\n";`

Comment: Your suggested Java snippet uses "double quotes [..] in source code", though.

Comment: @Jongware You can omit the second argument but then it will depend on the default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid placing string literals in your code is to use a file to read them from.  Note: you should consider clarity when looking at alternatives.  Ask yourself how is

```
Rep(programming language)
```

clearer/betters than

```
"programming language"
```

BTW: if you want to make your code unreadable, you can do this in Java

```
String s = \u0022programming language\u0022
```

Answer (score -1):

C++11 has a lot of new features for string literals.

- [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ - Raw string literals](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#raw-strings)
- [Wikipedia - C++11 - New string literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#New_string_literals)

Comment: Why the downvote? It is a pretty nice set of links here

Comment: I don't downvote because the information i interesting, but it doesn't answer the (less intersting) question "how to print text without double quotes?"

Comment: I think the fact that raw string literals still use `""` as *part* of their syntax doesn't exactly mean that it's the *same* syntax. The similarity is superficial IMO.